# Htaccess.. changing the domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a big Joomla website that was moved from .com to .eu domain.
The sites are on one web server.

On the old website there are a lot of links that point directly to oldwebsite.com/somethinghere.

Is there a way with Htaccess file in the old domains folder to redirect
from oldwebsite.com/somethinhere to newwebsite.eu/somethinghere?

Or maybe a way to do this on the new website folder?

Thank you,
Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways, some people recommend using RewriteEngine, but there is an easier way:

```
Redirect 301 / http://domain.eu/
```

This will automatically handle files in the domain -- for example, old.com/foo will be redirected to new.eu/foo

**EDIT:** Regarding "301", that is the code for a permanent redirect. There also exist temporary redirects (I believe the code is 302), but it sounds like what you need is exactly this - a permanent redirect.

**EDIT2:** Oh and, I think the / after domain.eu may be required, but I'm not 100% sure - doesn't hurt for it to be there, that's for sure! I know that because I use the same kind of a redirect on a production website.