# Sitewide redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, backend

I'm not sure if I should be asking this on serverfault, but here goes. I'm moving my website to another domain, and I want people going to the old one to be redirected to the new one, while staying on the same page. Is there any global setting I can modify (like `.htaccess`) to make that happen?

To clarify, I want this url:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/some/random/path.html
```

to redirect to this one:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/some/random/path.html
```

I included the `php` tag because I have a feeling that the answer may be in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess.. changing the domain name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005774/htaccess-changing-the-domain-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess has nothing do with PHP!

You can put the following rule into your .htaccess, which should solve your problem.

`RedirectPermanent / http://www.newdomain.com/`
(This triggers an 301 Redirect, but you can also use any other Redirect Command)

Comment: Will that keep the page? If so, awesome!

Comment: I fail to understand why this has two upvotes (at the moment) as it utterly fails to answer the question @Bluefire asked.

Comment: @Yokhannan why? It does exactly what was asked!